# Visual Studio 2015, DEP0001 : Непредвиденная ошибка: -2147014835

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Здравствуйте. Не получается задеплоить приложение на смартфон, Microsoft Lumia 640, Windows 10 Mobile, 10.1493.1066. Выводит ошибку: DEP0001 : Непредвиденная ошибка: -2147014835
Режим разработчика на обоих устройствах включен.
Эмуляторы запускаются, но не загружаются, висят на "Загрузка ОС". Подскажите, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: *Error 0x8007274d (-2147014835): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.* — Ругается на отсутствие связи с целевой машиной.

Comment: Спасибо, куда копать понял